# Select rows in data.frame based on two independent variables in R

Tags: r

Suggest i have a data.frame:

```
df<-mtcars
```

What I now want to do is select the row **before** `rowname ="Valiant"` and the row **after** `rowname = "Datsun 710"`
so that the **output looks like**:

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
Hornet 4 Drive 2  21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
select <- df[which(rownames(df)=="Valiant")-1,] | df[which(rownames(df)=="Datsun 710")+1, ] 

select <- df[ which((rownames(df) == "Valiant") -1 | (rownames(df)== "Datsun 710") +1) , ]

select <- df[(rownames(df) == "Valiant")-1 | (rownames(df) == "Datsun 710")+1, ] 

select <- df[ (which(rownames(df) == "Valiant") -1) | (which(rownames(df) == "Datsun 710") +1),  ]
```

But **non of them worked** although the **single code fragments work**:

```
> df[which(rownames(df)=="Valiant")-1,]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
> df[which(rownames(df)=="Datsun 710")+1, ]
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

What I'm I missing?

Comment: `df[(which(rownames(df)=="Valiant") - 1) : (which(rownames(df)=="Datsun 710") + 1), ]` maybe?

Comment: or df$rownames <- rownames(df), an then select the one you want.

Comment: @DavidArenburg maybe you need to post this as an answer

Comment: @DavidArenburg your answer return only 2 row? i think it must be all row between (which(rownames(df)=="Valiant") - 1) and (which(rownames(df)=="Datsun 710") + 1)...

Comment: @DavidArenburg if you change "Datsun 710" on something other f.e. "Cadillac Fleetwood" you got not 2 rows...

Comment: Yeah, you probably right, I haven't read the question myself, just looked on the output.

Comment: Well, your answer does just what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try 
`select <- df[ c(which((rownames(df) == "Valiant"))-1 ,which((rownames(df)== "Datsun 710")) +1) , ]`

because `which` return numeric , you can simply `c` all `which`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following answer:

```
  df[c(which(grepl(toupper("Datsun"),toupper(rownames(df))))+1,which(grepl(toupper("valiant"),toupper(rownames(df))))-1) , ]
```

This works for me :) !